# Building a query in Access to work with time

Tags: ms-access, time

This is my second post and it is about the same subject, I start to work with Access a little time, so I need your help to build one query that have some variables.

The scenarios

I need to do a query to show how many time one person remained inside the office, but the different of my first post is I need to see the details of operations.
The main list will be create one item when a person entry in the office and create other item when the person out the office, but exist some variables
1 – I have more one building
2 – Each building have a lot of turnstiles, and I need to define only the turnstile of main  hall
3 – Some times we have a system problems, and the system not create the item of entry / out

### Follow an example of list

### ID        Full Name           Date                Time      Status    Turnstile  Office

### 1   Andre Silva 02/25/2013  09:00 AM  In        03  SP

### 2   Andre Silva 02/25/2013  09:10 AM    In  05  SP

### 3   Andre Silva 02/25/2013  12:00 PM    Out 06  SP

### 4   Andre Silva 02/25/2013            12:10 PM  Out 02  SP

### 5   Andre Silva 02/25/2013            14:00 PM  In  02  SP

### 6   Andre Silva 02/25/2013  14:10 PM    In  05  SP

### 7   Andre Silva 02/25/2013            19:00 PM  Out 06  SP

### 8   Andre Silva 02/25/2013            19:10 PM  Out 02  SP

### 9   Andre Silva 02/26/2013  14:00 PM    In  03  BH

### 10  Andre Silva 02/26/2013            14:10 PM  In  05  BH

### 11  Andre Silva 02/26/2013            23:55 PM  Out 06  BH

### 12  Andre Silva 02/27/2013  01:10 AM    Out 03  BH

### 13  Andre Silva 02/28/2013            09:00 AM  In  03  RJ

### 14  Andre Silva 02/28/2013            09:10 AM  In  05  RJ

### 15  Andre Silva 02/28/2013            12:00 PM  Out 05  RJ

### 16  Andre Silva 02/29/2013            11:00  AM In  05  SP

### 17  Andre Silva 02/29/2013            17:10 PM  Out 06  SP

### 18  Andre Silva 02/29/2013  17:20 PM    Out 03  SP

Based in the main list I need create a query with this format

---

### Full Name       Date              Turnstile Time    Date     Turnstile   Time     Office    Total Time

### Andre Silva   02/25/2013    03  09:00 AM    02/25/2013   02  12:10 PM   SP  03:10

### Andre Silva   02/25/2013    02  14:00 PM    02/25/2013   02  19:10 PM   SP  05:10

### Andre Silva   02/26/2013    03  14:00 PM    02/27/2013   03  01:00 AM   BH  11:00

### Andre Silva   02/28/2013    03  09:10 AM                RJ  Not found a records of out

### Andre Silva             02/29/2013  03  17:20 PM    SP  Not found a records of in

I need see the interval between the in/out of turnstile 02/03 in the same office, and when one item of entry/out not found the answer should be 0.

I tried to use the standard queries of Access, like a crosstab or tried to create an expression with IFF, but no have success.

Thanks a lot
André

Comment: Not surprised, this is a bit of a git. Got an idea how to get close. Simplifier question though can you go in gate 2 then in gate 3 or vice versa. Or are they both outer gates?

Answer (score 0):

it is not answer but i have no time and this query may help you

```
SELECT 
  t1.FullName, 
  t1.Office, 
  t1.DateTime, 
  t1.status, 
  sum(IIf(isnull(t2.status),0,IIf(t2.status="In",1,-1))) AS deep_before, 
  sum(IIf(isnull(t2.status),0,IIf(t2.status="In",1,-1)))
    +IIf(t1.status="In",1,-1) AS deep_after
FROM Table1 AS t1 
  LEFT JOIN Table1 AS t2 ON (t1.FullName=t2.FullName) 
      AND (t1.Office=t2.Office) AND (t1.Datetime>t2.DateTime)
GROUP BY t1.FullName, t1.Office, t1.DateTime, t1.status;
```

tomorrow may be i see it again